# Angular 1.5 Firebase storage image upload

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there any example of image upload to firebase storage using Angular 1.5?

Is this example correct?
http://theanonymous.github.io/personal/2015/06/20/firebase/

Comment: MDN has a live demo of  [the FileReader.readAsDataURL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). That API creates a base64 string from the file which can be stored in Firebase. It is not the most efficient way to store binary data (33% overhead) but it works.

Comment: Also look at the [Firebase Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start)